# How to only get warnings from g++ compilation output

Tags: bash, g++

Currently I am using

```
g++ test.cpp 2> errors.txt
```

to only get errors from the g++ compilation output, however this redirects warnings too, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to only redirect error messages and keep warnings being sent to stdout?

Comment: Add -Werror and then you do not have warnings anymore :)

Comment: I suggest try to filter errors with grep. Alternative filter out warnings with grep -v .

Comment: It seems you do not want to take the warnings into account, this is a **very** bad idea, g++ does not produce warning against you but to **help** you, read them and solve the associated problems ;-) I also encourage you to increase the level of problem detection using the options `-pedantic -Wextra -Wall`

Comment: I do want to take warnings into account and have been using your suggested options previously. The issue is that I would like only the errors to be redirected to a file and for the warnings to remain in stdout, as I stated in my question.